# Best karate book

Tags: karate, books

Is there any book advices for learning karate. Previously I have trained in kickbox , muay-tai.I want to start learning karate.What are the best books for learning karate ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer will inherently be ephemeral. Tomorrow (and every day after that) someone will publish a karate book.  And the best book for learning Tang Su Do might not be the best book for learning Isshinryu.  The best book for a beginner will not be the best book for someone who has studied three other related arts.  The best book for a 98lb 78 year old marathon runner with arthritis won't be the best book for a 210lb weightlifter with a history of ACL tears.

Comment: Voted to close as being opinion based. Could also be closed as too broad.

Comment: As written, the question is both opinion based and too broad, but I suspect it could be refined to be better if the asker narrows down exactly what he is looking for.  There was a meta discussion related to this here:  http://meta.martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/75/book-recommendation-wiki

Comment: The best "book" for learning any martial art is the official syllabus of that style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you interested in the technical aspects of karate, or in the philosophical aspects?  I've found that seldom are both well represented.  I would say a good mix of both can be found in [Karate: Technique and Spirit by Tadashi Nakamura](http://books.google.ca/books?id=4PTFdFRl9MQC&dq=karate%20technique%20and%20spirit%20by%20tadashi%20nakamura&source=gbs_navlinks_s).  Nakamura is the founder of Seido, an offshoot of Kyokushin-Kai, but his technical demonstration in the book is well matched by his discussion on the role that martial arts can play in life.

Answer (score 0):

Although not a "technique and kata" writer, I would recommend anything by [Dave Lowry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dave_Lowry_(martial_arts)).  He is an excellent writer and will explain so much more about the etiquette of a Japanese martial art.